# Default back button stops working if I add a subview to a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I want to use a `UIVisualEffectView` as the background of a `UINavigationBar` because it achieves an effect that is distinct from simply setting `translucent = true` on the UINavigationBar.

I do this by subclassing `UINavigationController` and adding this to its `viewDidLoad()`

```
visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark))
visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
navigationBar.sendSubviewToBack(visualEffectView)
```

The `UIVisualEffectView` looks fine, and the other buttons in my navigation work properly, but the built-in back button (I did not customize it) stops working. I can still swipe to go back, but tapping the back button does not work. Removing the `UIVisualEffectView` restores the functionality of the back button.

I tried inspecting the view hierarchy in Xcode, and the `UIVisualEffectView` is not blocking the back button or anything like that.

Any idea what could be going on? Is there a better way to use the `UIVisualEffectView` as a background for a `UINavigationBar`, or is there additional setup I need to do?

Comment: if you read the docs for UINavigationController you'll find the following under navigationBar;

Discussion
It is permissible to customize the appearance of the navigation bar using the methods and properties of the UINavigationBar class but you must never change its frame, bounds, or alpha values or modify its view hierarchy directly. To show or hide the navigation bar, you should always do so through the navigation controller by changing its navigationBarHidden property 

By adding a subview to the navigationBar, you are indeed modifying its view's hierarchy.

Comment: I guess my question in that case is: Is there an alternate way to use a UIVisualEffectView in this manner?

Answer (score 13):

```
visualEffectView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Did the trick for me